# Increase size of rleaflet map in Jupyter Lab display (R in Jupyter)

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-lab, r-leaflet, jupyter-irkernel

When using R and rleaflet in a Jupyter Lab Notebook. My output map is short and wide with a vertical scroll box, and I can find no means of increasing it's height.

```
# Code to reproduce
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()

m
```

results in:
[image]

Comment: any updates regarding this issue? Did you find a solution ?